# Quantile Regression with multiple independent variables?

Tags: python, statsmodels, quantile-regression

Is it possible to run a Quantile REgression using multiple independent variables (x).
Using Python I tried statsmodel

```
mod = smf.quantreg(y, X)
res = mod.fit(q=.5)
print(res.summary())
```

Where y and X are Pandas dataframes. This works for OLS, however for quantile regression I does not.

How would you go about performing this?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not informative. What's the problem? Show the traceback if there is any.

Comment: you are using the formula interface with dataframes. use `sm.QuantReg` instead. https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression.QuantReg.html

Comment: `QuantReg` is the corresponding class to `OLS`. `quantreg` corresponds to `ols` which both need a formula and a DataFrame, e.g., `quantreg("y ~ 1 + x1 + x2", data)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do `quantreg` with multiple columns (when you don’t want to write out each variable) is to do something like this:

`Mod = smf.quantreg(f”y_var~ {' + '.join(df.columns[1:])}”)`

`Res = mod.fit(q=0.5)`

`print(res.summary())`

Where my y variable (`y_var`) is the first column in my data frame.

Comment: Please don't post [duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69482952/10871073) to different questions.